# module or name space not define error FS0039

Tags: constructor, f#

when i use other module in my current module it's says module or namespace not defined

```ml
module Cell

open CellState

type Cell = {CellID: int; RowID: string; State: CellState}
```

but actually i defined already `CellState` module in same project

Comment: Have you checked the file ordering? The file defining Cell needs to appear before your current module.  Exactly how you do this depends on the dev environment your using.

Comment: I marked this as a duplicate of a question that asks the same thing, but specifies the dotnet core environment. If you're not asking about dotnet core, please tell us what your environment is (but the answer is going to be essentially the same).